# Получения HTML из TinyMce

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

Добрый день!
Подскажите, как сохранять в базу данных контент из TinyMCE. 
При использовании tinymce.get("ContentPost").getContent() я получаю:

> [size= 12pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif]Как подать жалобу на незаконные действия и решения [/size]

Хотелось бы получать валидный HTML код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте указать формат получаемого контента:

```
tinymce.get("ContentPost").getContent({format: 'raw'});
```

[Источник](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/)